# Do someone know book, this page is taken from?

Tags: media, western-world, society

I've found a screenshot from some(western?) political comic book, but cannot understand what's this:

[image]

**Do someone know the origin and what's this about?**

Comment: Downvotes usually mean people think the question is of poor quality, It might help to clarify, for example, where you found this image, what you want to know about its context, or how you've already tried to find the source.

Comment: Don't think so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an photograph taken from a graphic novel *[Survivors of the Holocaust](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Survivors-Holocaust-Kath-Shackleton/dp/1445150433/)*

It retells in cartoon form six stories:

> Based on a series of a BAFTA-nominated animated documentaries, the artwork in Survivors of the Holocaust has been reinvented to bring together six different real-life survivors' account of the Holocaust.

It is aimed at 9-12 year olds.

The story is told by [Martin Kapel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dl-PUfTBjzU) so you can watch the video.

This particular scene has a mother and two children, Martin and his sister. In 1938, members of the Polish Jewish community in Germany were rounded up and put on trains bound for Poland. At the border, Martin and his family were ordered to walk along the railway tracks into Poland.  Of course the Polish border guards (police and army) tried to prevent this. This page represents the border guards taking Martin's family prisoner. What the Poles were trying to do was send Martin and the others back to Germany, But the Germans were ready for that and attempts by the Polish border guards failed.

Martin's family managed to reach Krakow and Martin and his sister were lucky because they became part of the Kindertransport, and allowed to move to England.  His mother also survived, but the rest of his family were murdered.

Comment: I might note that your particular image is used on Russian anti-semitic sites, which I shan't link to.

Comment: Emm, no, it's not - it was taken from russian livejournal. I can give you a link, if you wish. Interesting - journal seems to be from Israel, "bad side" is polish, and anti-semitic is Russia! How can it be, can you explain?))))) Also, what are you doing on such sites?

Comment: don't you have an answer?

Comment: I have the link, thank you, my google-fu is good enough.  I shall try to explain a little of the context.

Comment: I've found the link, so I can now tell you the actual story.

Comment: I've read it at last - great! Thanks a lot - it brings much more context now